# What is the right pcap filter string to capture packets sent to IP address 10.24.11.73 and UDP port 32806?

Tags: libpcap, winpcap

I want to capture outgoing UDP packets sent to IP address 10.24.11.73 and destination port number 32806. so I set

```
pcap_setdirection(*pchandle, PCAP_D_OUT);
```

but my problem is the filter string (const char *) passed to

```
pcap_compile(*pchandle, &program, filter, 0, subnet);
```

I looked at PCAP-FILTER and tried different string combination but non seems to work.
can some one help me with this issue. what should the filter string be set to in order to capture the intended packets.

I am using WinPcap and Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

You'd want something like this:

```
"udp and dst host 10.24.11.73 and dst port 32806"
```